# How to bind map of custom objects using @RequestBody from JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I need to send map of custom objects `Map<String, Set<Result>>` from frontend to backend.

So I think it should be possible to build JSON, send it to Controller via Ajax and receive it in Controller via `@RequestBody` annotation which should bind json to object. right?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadReport", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getReport(@RequestBody Map<String, Set<Result>> resultMap) 
{
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("resultMap", resultMap);
    return createPDF("pdf-report", context);
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "item": {
        "id": 3850,
        "name": "iti"
      },
      "severity": "low",
      "code": "A-M-01",
      "row": 1,
      "column": 1,
      "description": "Miscellaneous warning"
    }
  ]
}
```

Model:

```
public class Result {
    private Integer id;
    private Item item;
    private String severity;
    private String code;
    private Integer row;
    private Integer column;
    private String description;
    //getter & setters
    //hashCode & equals
}
public class Item {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    //getter & setters
}
```

After send such a JSON like above by ajax I am getting error message from browser:

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect
```

If I change JSON to send empty set like below then it works but of course my map has empty set:

```
{"result": []}
```

So, Why I am not able to receive filled map with set of objects? Why binding/unmarshalling do not work as expected and what I should do to make it works?

Note:
I am using Jackson library and marshalling for other case for `@ResponseBody` works fine. Problem is with unmarshalling and binding object via `@RequestBody`.

Answer (score 1):

In order for jackson to properly deserialize your custom classes you need to provide `@JsonCreator` annotated constructor that follows one of the rules defined in the [java doc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html).  So for your `Item` class it could look like this:

```
@JsonCreator
public Item(@JsonProperty("id") Integer id,
            @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to deal with map differently,
first create wrapper class

```
public MyWrapperClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Map<String, List<String>> fil = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    // getters and setters
    }
```

then you should take request in controller,

```
@PostMapping
    public Map<String,List<String>> get(@RequestBody Filter filter){
    System.out.println(filter);
    }
```

Json Request should be like

```
{  
       "fil":{  
          "key":[  
             "value1",
             "value2"
          ],
          "key":[  
             "vakue1"
          ]
       }
    }
```